# Windows 2012R2 connecting to remote SQL2012 Server issue PHP Apache

Tags: php, sql-server, windows, apache, wamp

I have created a local project that connects to a SQL2012 database. On my local machine I have Windows 7 64Bit enterprise, with MS SQL drivers with no problem at all. I moved the project over to a Windows Server 2012R2 production machine. I got the web server up and PHP working fine.

I checked the phpinfo() file and sql drivers are enabled and sqlsrv is a 'registered stream'

I have try & catch blocks for all my connections to the database. No errors

I have checked the Apache error logs and there is no indication of a problem connecting to the DB.

My project uses SQL authentication, using a Username and Password - not built in Windows Authentication. I tried to change the password to a incorrect one ---> still no error?!!

I even tried to disable Domain, Public, and Private Window Firewalls. Still nothing.

I'm totally stumped, perhaps someone here may have some ideas.

Does anyone know if the SQLSRV30 pack is compatible with Windows 2012R2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I have figured out what the problem was, I needed to install Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Native Client located at: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065#

After that installed everything is working fine.